# Lock Record in Dictionary - ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, locking, concurrentdictionary

Multi-Threaded application , using static dictionary . which will be used to process the request , each request will access only one record .

Processing the Request

1. Read Record
2. Algorithm to calculate the values
3. Update the record.

During the process that particular record needs to blocked .

```
static Dictionary<string, InstacneLevel> objlevel; -- Static variable

lock (key)
{
  // need to lock required key 
  // read , Calclulate and update the value for that key
}
```

I dont find any Clue , can anyone please help me out.

Can i go with ConcurrentDictionary??

Comment: i dont want to lock entire dictionary , just want to lock one record , because other thread can process with other records ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy answser is "yes, use concurrentdictionary", but before you do, take care to read this article which explains its deficiencies and performance penalties.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548406/Dictionary-plus-Locking-versus-ConcurrentDictionar

Comment: I think , when i update the value in concurrent dictionary it internally lock d record and thread safe . But i don't find option to lock the record to particular code block to be execute.

Comment: Ok, I understand. In which case if the Key is a string object then writing a wrapper class and hiding the instance of the dictionary inside it as a private, then implementing your own IDictionary interface on your wrapper class (with appropriate exclusive locks using the string Key value as required by your business logic) is the way to go.

Comment: Ok, I Got it . Do you have any reference article for this implementation ? if so it would be definitely helpful . Thanks